# How to smooth datatable of 15 entries to 100 entries?

Tags: c#

I have a datatable with 15 entries. I would like to transform it to a datatable of 100 entries by calculating the "floating average" between 2 points in c#.

I don't know if I am clear enough just let me know

Comment: Provide what you have done till now.

Comment: but if you want the average of 15 taking 2 points per time you will have 29 elements (15 originals + 14 averages). How you want get the others 71 entries?

Comment: I want to get the 71 others entries by doing the same " game" of floating average the 29 elements

Comment: Ok I get it now. Provide what you have done till now. Are you using System.Data.DataTable?

Comment: Yes I do use System.Datat.DataTable .

Comment: There isn't a way to magically do it; you'll need to use some intermediate data structure (i.e. a list of points) in order to achieve your goal. Walk each point in turn and calc the average between it and the next one. Then do the same again with the larger set. Posting your original data structure and what you've tried so far would be helpful and encourage more activity around your question.

Comment: Some questions you need to answer for yourself: 1) do you always want 6 new entries between two given entries or do you want some regular interval along whatever you use for X axis? 2) Do you want the new point to be on a straight line between the given points, or should it be more curved?

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for an algorithm that will interpolate between points. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation

Comment: Check my answer bellow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@francops henri i beleave it's this what you want:

```
public static void YourProcessName(DataTable dt, string columnName, int maxRows)
{
    var rcount = dt.Rows.Count;

    while (rcount < maxRows)
    {
        var max = (dt.Rows.Count - 1) * 2;

        for (var i = 0; i < max; i += 2)
        {
            var avg = ((double)dt.Rows[i][columnName] + (double)dt.Rows[i + 1][columnName]) / 2;

            var nRow = dt.NewRow();

            nRow[columnName] = avg;

            dt.Rows.InsertAt(nRow, i + 1);

            rcount++;

            if (rcount == maxRows) break;
        }
    }
}
```

It's important that the type of your column be double like this test:

```
var dt = new DataTable();

dt.Columns.Add("Number", typeof(double));

for (double i = 0; i < 150; i += 10)
{
    var row = dt.NewRow();

    row["Number"] = i;

    dt.Rows.Add(row);
}

YourProcessName(dt, "Number", 100);
```

You can change the "Double" type but make sure you'll remember to replace everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution for 106 values:

```
int k = 0;
double a;
double b;
double[] coarse;
double[] fine;

for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
    {
      a = 1.0 - j * 1.0/7;
      b = 1.0 - a;

      fine[k++] = a * coarse[i] + b * coarse[i+1];
    }

fine[k] = coarse[14];
```

This assumes that the 15 original values are stored in array coarse[].
The interpolated values will end in array fine[].